# Pointer to const overloaded member function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, c++11

I have a class with const-overloaded accessor methods to a member. These accessors are declared using `decltype`, and it's a convention that my colleagues follow.  Now, I need to create a pointer to the const version of the accessor function. I am trying to use result_of to do that, but I haven't had any success. Could someone help?

```
#include<type_traits>

class A{
    int _member;
    public:
    const decltype(_member) &member() const;
    decltype(_member) &member();    
};

std::result_of<static_cast<const A *>(nullptr)->member()>::type (A::*fnPtr)() const = &A::member;
```

Comment: You don't want `result_of` there. You want `decltype`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
decltype(std::declval<const A&>().member()) (A::*fnPtr)() const = &A::member;
```

Comment: `decltype(static_cast<const A *>(nullptr)->member()) (A::*fnPtr)() const = &A::member;`

I tried this before I saw you answer, and that worked too. Is it bad practice to do what I did?

Comment: @user2308211 Either works. Using `declval` is more idiomatic and shorter, and makes it easier to control the value category (`declval<A>()` is an rvalue, `declval<A&>()` is an lvalue).